# WPF put a group box in the middle or inside a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a user control named Palabok:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NeocClinic.WPFSystem.Templatas.Palabok"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

then I implement it to my WPF Window:

```
<Window x:Class="NeocClinic.WPFSystem.IrritantDetailsForm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:windowsControls="clr-namespace:NeocClinic.WPFSystem.Templatas"
        Title="IrritantDetailsForm" Height="300" Width="300">
    <windowsControls:Palabok ></windowsControls:Palabok>
</Window>
```

My problem is I want to add a Group Box (with personalized components/controls of Irritants) to the Window that will be displayed in the Grid.Column="2" of the Palabok user control. Then I will use the same user control to another WPF window but put an Image control to the Grid.Column="2" instead of a Group Box, of the Palabok user control, but I can's seem to put the controls inside the Palabok user control.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Control should inherit from **ItemsControl**

Please check : http://drwpf.com/blog/category/item-containers/